# Force dhcp client to get a new lease

Tags: linux, dhcp

I have a linux DHCP server running on my network. i recently found out that i can assign specific ip address to clients based on their mac address by modifying the dhcpd.conf file.

Now is there something i can do from the server side that would invalidate a specific clients lease forcing it to get a new one from the server (after i have added entries in dhcpd.conf) to make it get a particular ip address without releasing / renewing on the client side ?

thank you, ankit

Comment: Assuming dhclient, use `dhclient -l`

Comment: i was looking for doing something on the server side, not on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the client will not contact the DHCP server again until the lease has expired.  You'll have to go to the client and tell it to try again.